# What conditons on the derivatives of f and g are required for the following limit to be true?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-explanation

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)-g(x)}{x^n} = 0$$

Where f and g are arbitrary functions that are polynomials.

I know that for this limit to exist, I need my numerator to approach zero faster than the denominator for $x$ values near $0$. To achieve this, I have tried several approach to discover patterns between different functions.

For example I discovered that $x^n$ will always approach $0$ faster than $x^{n-1}$. And additionally, the successive derivatives of each of these will also have the same relationship (Please correct me if I am wrong about this property, I only came to this conclusion after testing several couplets of functions.)

Therefore, I came to the conclusion that one of the conditions is that $f(x)-g(x)$ should have a higher power than $x^n$. However, I am unsure if this is the only conditon. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I will just mention that $f$ and $g$ might not be be continuous, let alone polynomials, and this can still be true.

Comment: @ElliotG for this question it is possible to assume both f and g are continuous polynomials.

Comment: It's always possible to assume that, but you also said that $f$ and $g$ are arbitrary functions, and its going to be pretty hard to every say much about arbitrary functions.

Answer (score 2):

Let $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$, and assume that $h$ has derivatives at $0$ of all orders up to and including $n$. Then Taylor's formula shows that your condition $\lim_{x \to 0} h(x)/x^n = 0$ occurs if and only if $h(0) = h'(0) = h''(0) = \dots = h^{(n)}(0) = 0$.

If, as you say in the revised question, $f$ and $g$ are polynomials, then we can simply say that $f$ and $g$ should have identical terms of degree $\leq n$.

Comment: What about $h(x)=x$?

Comment: @ElliotG When $n$ is what?

Comment: $1$. Im just pointing out that $h'(0)=1$ but the limit still exists.

Comment: @ElliotG Say $n = 1$ and $h(x) = x$. In that case, it's false that $\lim_{x \to 0} h(x)/x = 0$, and it's also false that $h(0) = h'(0) = 0$. Where's the problem?

Comment: Right but if $h(x)=x$ and $n=1$ then you have $h'(0)=1$, but the limit still goes to zero.

Comment: @David I'm not quite sure how your answer for f and g being polynomials makes sense. For example, here is a counterexample which does not work:

lim(x->0)((x^3+x)-(x^3+2x^2))/x^4

Comment: @ElliotG In that case $\lim_{x \to 0} h(x)/x = 1 \ne 0$. The two statements I claim to be equivalent in general are both false in this case.

Comment: where the numerator is f(x) - g(x) (as represented by the brackets).

Comment: my mistake. its too late for me to be doing this.

Comment: You're talking about the second part of my answer, right? In that case, the polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ you wrote *do not* agree for terms of degree $\leq 4$, and the limit you wrote doesn't exist (and therefore is not $0$). So the limit condition is false and the criterion I gave is not satisfied. I don't see the problem.

Comment: @David I think I am interperating your condtition incorrectly then. Do you not mean that all variables in my numerator should be to the power of atleast n-1? (Where the denominator has power n?)

Comment: Once you've performed the subtraction, the remaining terms should all have degree at least $n + 1$.

Comment: I still don't fully understand.. For example, does this fit your conditions? lim(x->0)((x^3+x^2)-(x^3+2x^2))/x^4

Because this limit does not exist either.

Comment: No, in that case, $f$ and $g$ don't have the same term of order $2$.